# Regular Expression in PigStorage()

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am kid of struck while loading a log file into hdfs via pig. 
Basically this log files has WebSphere Server exceptions for analytics.

Now while breaking components of exception details and loading into schema, I am not able to specify the regex into PigStorage constructor.

My code:

```
inputFile = load '/datalake/xxx/yyy/bd_cni/log_analytics_project/raw_data/APSRP7420/SystemOut_16.05.22_11.46.13.log' USING PigStorage('\[\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s+\d+\:\d+\:\d+\:\d+\s+\w+\]') as (someColumnName:chararray);
```

Error which I am getting:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 147>  Unexpected character '['
Details at logfile: /home/rshukla8/pig_1466510599995.log
```

I am totally novice to PIG and Unix so any pointer here will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PigStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#PigStorage) cannot be instanciated with a regex, instead, you can use `MyRegExLoader(String pattern)` of the [piggybank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) library

```
inputFile = load '/datalake/xxx/yyy/bd_cni/log_analytics_project/raw_data/APSRP7420/SystemOut_16.05.22_11.46.13.log' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MyRegExLoader('\[\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s+\d+\:\d+\:\d+\:\d+\s+\w+\]') as (someColumnName:chararray);
```

Comment: Well, this still says : 
2016-06-21 09:16:51,704 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 1, column 181>  Unexpected character '"'
Details at logfile: /home/rshukla8/pig_1466518430361.log


Also whats the shortest way to check if PiggyBank has been registered successfully. I got following message when I register it: 
 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS

Comment: this is not an error, its just an info ! do tried to dump something ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the PiggyBankCombinedLogLoader as below

```
 REGISTER '<path of piggybank jar>/piggybank.jar'; 

    logs = LOAD '/in/combined_access_log' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.apachelog.CombinedLogLoader()
                AS (addr: chararray, logname: chararray, user: chararray, time: chararray,
                    method: chararray, uri: chararray, proto: chararray,
                    status: int, bytes: int, referer: chararray, userAgent: chararray);
```

Comment: Alright - now i have a question , how do I install the piggybank ? I download the relevant mapr-pig_0.13.201507291647_all.deb file and placed in my datalake folder :|

Comment: @Rohit You can download piggyBank.jar and give the path, I have edited the ans please check